# Informação armazenada e mostrada errada

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
    var marcas = {
        nome: '',
        fipeId: ''    
    };

    var marcasVet = [];
    var select;


$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://fipeapi.wipsites.com.br/carros/marcas',

    success: function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            marcas.nome = data[i].name;
            marcas.fipeId = data[i].id;            


            marcasVet[i] = marcas;

            select += '<p> Marca: ' + marcasVet[i].nome + ' Marca id (Fipe): ' + marcasVet[i].fipeId + '</p>';

        }

        $('#info').html(select);
    }

});
```

Os dados são armazenados no vetor `marcasVet[]` e mostrados dentro de uma div com `id="info"`

O problema é que ao pedir para mostrar a informação de `marcas.fipeId` ele apenas mostra o valor `120`, em qualquer posição do vetor `marcasVet[]`.

Trocando o código `$('#info').html(select);` para `$('#info').html(marcasVet[10].fipeId);`  ou qualquer outra posição (1,2,3,4...87) ele mostra apenas o valor `120`.

Gostaria que mostrasse o valor que ele mostra quando altera para a var `select`.

Alguém sabe onde está o erro?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zere novamente o valor da variável `marcas` dentro do `for`. E use o método `push()` para adicionar o objeto em seu vetor `marcasVet`. Veja:

```js
    
var marcas = {nome: '', fipeId: ''};
var marcasVet = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 
  marcas = {nome: '', fipeId: ''};
  
  marcas.nome = "Nome "+i;
  marcas.fipeId = "Fipe "+i;
  
  marcasVet.push(marcas);
}

console.log(marcasVet);
```

Comment: saberia me informar porque eu preciso zerar novamente o valor da variável marcas sendo que eu vou alterando o valor dela a cada incremento? Estou tendo outro problema so que agora com 2 loops onde tem um array que cada indice deveria receber um novo array. Mas, na hora de colocar o array dentro do outro ele imprime certo mas quando finaliza diz que é undefined